# javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse SC_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS

Tags: java, http

Feel free to close if this doesn't really belong on StackOverflow.

`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse` has a bunch of useful constants (such as `SC_BAD_REQUEST`, `SC_NOT_FOUND` etc) but for some reason there isn't one for HTTP 429. Is there another place to find such a constant? Is there a reason it was omitted from the class?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why they omitted it, but you can send an error with the `sendError(int i, String s)` method of `HttpServletResponse`. This takes an int as the first argument, so you can simply use `429` as the parameter. The second argument takes the error message. For this you could use the phrase "Too many requests".

If you are using the Spring framework then you can also use `HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS.value()` if you really want to use a constant.